# Xcode 7- CocoaPod AlamoFire & Others, imports into Project but is not working inside of project

Tags: swift, swift2, cocoapods, xcode7

I Am able to get the alamofire cocoapod imported into the project, but when I try to use the pod, Xcode does not seem to recognize that it is there.

Edit: I am working from the XCWorkspace

Comment: Maybe you have opened project instead of workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the .xcworkspace instead of the xo.xcodeproj?

I'm not entirely sure of your problem, but if they're in your project but you can't use them in code, did you make sure to import them at the top of the file you're trying to use them in?

Comment: Yes, the pods have been imported at the top of the project. The strange thing is that  I put the import statement at the top of the file and the compiler doesn't throw any errors, making it seem like the pod can be used. I will then attempt to write some code, but  I cannot access any of the code from the pod.